# how to show toast when plain text(no link) is touched in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

I want to show a toast when user clicks on plain text in web view not on the link. please understand the condition

if i set web View Client then links are fine but can not show toast for plain text.

if i set on touch listener then toast is shown for plain text but links are not working.

So please tell me what to do to handle it. thanks in advance.